# Prove that a bounded continuous function on $(a,b)$ can continuously extend to $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a doubt that whether a bounded continuous function on $(a,b)$ can continuously extend to $[a,b]$. I think it may be an exercise in the standard analysis books. However, I can't find such exercise. Is the statement true? How to prove it?

Comment: You can do that extension if and only if the function is uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Rigel I know that theorem. However, here I assume that $f$ is also bounded, so maybe that's different?

Comment: No, because if $f$ is uniformly continuous on the bounded interval $(a,b)$ then it is automatically bounded. Anyway, the function given in the answer $f(x) = \sin (1/x)$, $x\in (0,1)$ is bounded but cannot be extended with continuity at $0$.

Comment: @Rigel the second sentence in your comment is correct, but the first misses the point (you are saying "no, because it is true under a strictly stronger assumption [uniform continuity]." This does not mean per se the result is false under the weaker assumption (boundedness), although in this case it turns out it is)

Comment: Sorry, the comment was referred to my first comment (with the "if and only if" condition clearly stated), so I has been sloppy.

Comment: You can only do so if and only if the limits at the end points $a, b$ exist. Just having a bounded function won't guarantee this because there may be oscillatory behavior at the end points. Uniform continuity gives you the Cauchy condition at each point of the interval (including end points) and hence assures the existence of limit at each point and you have a continuous extension possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function $sin(1/x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: (+1) Good example. I was thinking about $\sin\left(\frac1{1-x^2}\right)$ on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have continuity on $[ a , b]$ we need to define $f(a)$ as the right limit of $f$ at $x=a$ and $f(b)$ as the left limit of $f$ at $x=b.$ If one of these right or left limits fails to exist then the continuous extension is not possible. $f(x)=cos(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$ is a counter example.